# Target URL accessibility and content availability checker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react application. In my application I have feature by which user can enter URL to refer something and save them for later use.

Some sample target url eg: Slack channel link for contact, SSO authenticated git hub repo link, google drive document link, box document link etc.

Now the scenario is that sometimes User entered URLs fail to load target url content, when I try to open the saved URLs later. Some possible cases:

1. Document URL never existed
2. Document URL was working at time of save but document removed later, so now not working

So, I want to ***implement Target URL checker functionality in my react web application something like chrome bookmark checker extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-checker/eeckiajfclogcacnhgigljkcgabfcmco?hl=en) functionality***, by which I can ensure that the Targeting URL is loadable in browser with 200 status or not and content availability in the document.

I tried to hit the target url by axios and checked the response status received in it but that approach was not working for Some cases like:

1. Target url is an url of an sso authentic web application, in that case it return 302 due to redirection for sso authentication login page
2. Targeted url is an url of application which using cookies for authentication, so always treating that as unauthorised even I have authenticated myself for the application in my browser in another tab
3. Targeted url is an url of site, that redirecting to another url
4. Getting CORS issue for all URLs

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please do suggest some approach. Thanks!

Comment: Add your code and what you tried to the question

Comment: Added some screenshot with some sample static data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a frontend-only solution such as you are building at the moment, I don't think you can solve the problem very well. You will stumble upon a number of challenges that might make the endeavour impossible, for example:

- [CORS rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) not letting you access URLs at all.
- [Mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) rules not allowing you to access non-encrypted URLs from a TLS-encrypted page.
- Broken/self-sigend SSL certificates.

I would propose that you move the URL checks to a backend system that can freely open HTTP(s) connections without the restrictions of a browser.